# Invalid User Data Pusher Next JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next-auth

Hey guys recently I am practicing pusher with next js but I stumbled upon this problem where it says

Error: Invalid user data: 'presence-channel' and i cannot seem to fix it no matter how many times i try can someone help me with pointing out where i am wrong below is the error

[image]

**api/index.js file**

```
import { pusher } from "../../../lib/pusher";

// presence channel handler
export default async function handler(req, res) {
  const { message, username } = req.body;
  // trigger a new post event via pusher
  await pusher.trigger("presence-channel", "chat-update", {
    message,
    username,
  });

  res.json({ status: 200 });
}
```

**api/pusher/auth**

```
import { pusher } from "../../../../lib";

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  const { socket_id, channel_name, username } = req.body;

  const randomString = Math.random().toString(36).slice(2);

  const presenceData = {
    user_id: randomString,
    user_info: {
      username,
    },
  };

  try {
    var auth = pusher.authenticateUser(socket_id, channel_name, presenceData);
    res.send(auth);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}
```

**lib/index.js**

```
import Pusher from "pusher";

export const pusher = new Pusher({
  appId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PUSHER_APP_ID,
  key: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PUSHER_KEY,
  secret: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PUSHER_SECRET,
  cluster: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PUSHER_CLUSTER,
  useTLS: true,
});
```

**pages/chat.js**

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Pusher from "pusher-js";
import axios from "axios";

export default function Chat({ username }) {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");
  const [displayMessage, setDisplayMessage] = useState([]);
  const [onlineUserCount, setOnlineUserCount] = useState(0);

  console.log(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PUSHER_APP_ID);

  const pusher = new Pusher(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PUSHER_KEY, {
    cluster: "ap2",
    authEndpoint: `api/pusher/auth`,
    auth: { params: { username } },
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const channel = pusher.subscribe("presence-channel");

    channel.bind("pusher:subscription_succeeded", (members) => {
      setOnlineUserCount(members.count);
    });

    channel.bind("pusher:member_added", (member) => {
      setOnlineUserCount(channel.member.count);

      setOnlineUserCount((prevState) => {
        [...prevState, { username: member.info.username }];
      });
    });

    channel.bind("chat-update", (data) => {
      const { message, username } = data;
      setDisplayMessage((prevState) => {
        [...prevState, { message, username }];
      });
    });

    return () => {
      pusher.unsubscribe("presence-channel");
    };
  }, []);

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    await axios.post("/api/pusher/chat-update", {
      message,
      username,
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {username}
      {displayMessage.map((chat, id) => {
        return <div key={id}>{chat.message}</div>;
      })}

      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input
          type="text"
          onChange={(e) => setMessage(e.target.value)}
          placeholder="Enter Message"
        />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**pages/index.js**

```
import Head from "next/head";

export default function Home({ handleLoginChange, handleLogin }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>Dealer</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>

      <div>
        <form onSubmit={handleLogin}>
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="enter your username"
            onChange={handleLoginChange}
          />
          <button>Login</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**_app.js**

```
import "../styles/globals.css";
import { useState } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const router = useRouter();

  const handleLogin = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    router.push("/chat");
  };

  return (
    <Component
      handleLoginChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}
      username={username}
      handleLogin={handleLogin}
      {...pageProps}
    />
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

Answer (score 0):

The authenticateUser method only accepts 2 arguments. The second argument should be user data.

```
// Replace this with code to retrieve the actual user id and info
const user = {
  id: "some_id",
  user_info: {
    name: "John Smith",
  },
  watchlist: ['another_id_1', 'another_id_2']
};

const auth = pusher.authenticateUser(socket_id, user);
```

[Link to docs](https://pusher.com/docs/channels/server_api/authenticating-users/)